# Improving Canvas Performance with Transparency

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

Drawing images that contain transparency is slow.

**Is there any way of just discarding the pixels that contain transparency?**

When I draw images that do not contain any transparent pixels, it's really fast.

Comment: No sufficient information is being given. Show us your code or we'll not be able to help you.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho I would but there's a hell of a lot of it in a dozen files. What sort of information(/code) is missing? (I mean, we know how to draw an image to a canvas.)

Comment: you should provide the minimum amount of code that can reproduce your problem. If your problematic code lies on a huge project, it's a good idea to try to isolate it from the rest to see what happens, and while you're there, paste the isolated thing in your question. ;)

Comment: I'm not saying so because I'm lazy, but from my side it's really too difficult to get what the problem might be, and I really doubt it comes from the image's `alpha` channel.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho ah, got you! Will update it with some code and get back to you. :)

Comment: What do you mean by slow? drawImage is like one of the fastest operations on canvas, even with transparency. The only culprit I could imagine would be antialiasing process (which should still be very fast), so you could try disabling it with the [prefix]ImageSmoothingEnabled parameter set to false, but I'm really dubitative your ptoblem really lies in here.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can obtain a context with no alpha support. the slowness is likely coming from the background compositing the browser have to do with the element and each time something is drawn. here's how (notice the option at the end)

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d', {alpha:false});
```

you can still composite transparency locally inside the canvas but the background will always stay opaque. i think most browsers support it but i wouldn't hold onto my hat for ie11 or older.

Comment: That will just set the backround of your canvas to opaque, drawImage will still treat transparent pixels from the source as transparent.